# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() when using UiAutomation in a test

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

Whenever I try to use [`UiAutomation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html) in any test through `getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation()`, the process crashes with this exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=30334, uid=2000, (need uid=1000) is not allowed to send as package android
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
        at android.app.IUiAutomationConnection$Stub$Proxy.disconnect(IUiAutomationConnection.java:225)
        at android.app.UiAutomation.disconnect(UiAutomation.java:240)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.finish(Instrumentation.java:197)
        at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:575)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1837)
```

Any idea why? I'm using Gradle through Android Studio, tried various versions, calling it directly through `adb`, even without any external dependency (and obviously with at least SDK 18)... Always crashing.

This is the only official example I've found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SlBHUW0ybM

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This isn't an answer for why UIAutomator isn't catching the error, but rather a possible workaround that I found. When accessibility services are on I am unable to get an UIAutomator dump because I receive the error you described. When I turn off TalkBack and/or Switch Access in the Accessibility settings I no longer get the Permission Denial error and UIAutomator dump works successfully. Not sure if this will help you, but I can reproduce your issue every time with accessibility services ON in Lollipop(Nexus 5).

Comment: For me is was LastPass.

Comment: @JakeWharton You had this issue with LastPass - how did you figure it out that it was LastPass and what did you do to fix? I have both TalkBack and Switch Access off and I'm still getting this error on Android 6.0 but not on 5.1.1.

Comment: Dough! There was another 3rd party app using accessibility services, disabled that and voila!

Comment: Same here, disable all Accessibility services and the exception is gone.

Comment: I disabled LastPass and the SecurityException was gone. Wow, great catch.

Comment: Did anybody submit the bug to Google?

Comment: I had to turn off 'Nova Launcher' on my Galaxy S6 (Settings>Accessibility>Services)

Comment: That's weird, I hope someone could give us a explaination

Answer (score 8):

Use `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` instead of `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()`

Comment: Thanks, works for me. In kotlin with androidx it it is: `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext`