# Security exception from UIAutomator test

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

My UI automator test runs green on a (Lollipop) emulator, but gives this error on a Sony Xperia Z1 (Lollipop 5.1.1). Any ideas ? Workaround?

```
11-24 20:15:00.432 29892-29892/uk.co.xxx.tm D/LifecycleMonitor: Lifecycle status change: uk.co.xxx.tm.TmActivity@17d33faf in: STOPPED
11-24 20:15:00.433 29892-29892/uk.co.xxx.tm D/LifecycleMonitor: Lifecycle status change: uk.co.xxx.tm.TmActivity@17d33faf in: DESTROYED
11-24 20:15:00.460 29892-29932/uk.co.xxx.tm I/MonitoringInstrumentation: waitForActivitiesToComplete() took: 402ms
11-24 20:15:00.479 29892-29932/uk.co.xxx.tm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner Process: uk.co.xxx.tm, PID: 29892                                                                java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=29854, uid=2000, (need uid=1000) is not allowed to send as package android
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1553)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1505)
at android.app.IUiAutomationConnection$Stub$Proxy.disconnect(IUiAutomationConnection.java:225)
at android.app.UiAutomation.disconnect(UiAutomation.java:241)
at android.app.Instrumentation.finish(Instrumentation.java:198)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.finish(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:232)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.finish(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:248)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:237)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
```

Answer (score 6):

As per [java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() when using UiAutomation in a test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132799/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-getintentsender-when-using-uia), I checked Accessibility settings and it's now running green with TalkBack and Switch Access both off.

Comment: Thanks man! I had almost the same issue. I have a password manager app (Dashlane) installed on the device, and it uses the accessibility feature of the OS to fill in the passwords inside the apps. This messes up the permissions somehow. I had to turn off/disable this integration/feature (in Settings > Accessibility) while running tests.

Comment: Huge thanks from me, too. Had an app "Super Cleaner" installed which runs a service and is also listed in the Accessibility settings. This answer saved me A LOT of time